# Most recent changes done to the project

Tags: tfs

I have couple of projects in which one or more files have been updated. These updates need not change the *.proj file but the overall project dll is changed.

Each project can have multiple folders and each folder can have multiple files.

Is there a way in TFS to know which file was when updated last?

Comment: Do you mean within a single check-in, or just which files were updated in the last check-in?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply see a list of changesets, then you can by going to:

- View -> Source Control Explorer
- Ctrl-G
- Find
- All Changesets and select $/Team project

That will give you a list of all changes.

You can get a more fine grained control of this using the:

```
tf history
```

Command; something like this:

```
tf history /recursive $/Project
```

I believe that if you wanted to list each file then you would have to go to the API.